# Uniform Density Curves: John and Oliver

Tags: statistics, density-function

The problem I'm having trouble understanding is noted below:

*Records show that Oliver is typically 10–30 minutes late for his shift at work. The distribution for the minutes he is late forms a consistent pattern, which can be graphed as the given uniform density curve.*

[image]

*John and Oliver are working a shift that starts at the same time. John always arrives 8 minutes late.  What percentage of the time does Oliver arrive within 10 minutes of John's arrival time?*

My first step in finding the solution was to multiply the 10 (the minutes within the time that Oliver arrives of John's arrival time) and $\frac{1}{20}$, the height of the density curve. The answer then would be 50%. However, this is not the correct answer. How would you find the correct answer to this problem?

Comment: It says he arrives “*within* 10 minutes” of John’s arrival time. If John always arrives 8 minutes late, what does that tell you about how many minutes late Oliver can be?

Comment: @symplectomorphic 18 minutes(?)

Comment: $X \sim \mathsf{Unif}(10,30),$ you seek $P(X \le 18).$ In R, where `punif` is a uniform CDF: the computation is `punif(18, 10,30).` which returns $0.4,$ and that is $8(1/20).$ Why would that be the answer?